# Symfony : RedirectToRoute or GenerateUrl

Tags: redirect, symfony, redirecttoroute

All in subject ^^

What's the best for redirect :

```
RedirectToRoute('my_route', [my_params]);
```

or

```
RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('my_route', [my_params]);
```

and why ?

I did not find a good answer in doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is exactly the same.

The first is only meant to be easier to use ...

See this note :

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-new-shortcut-methods-for-controllers